# SSD not working in Windows 10 (write protected)

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, read-only

I just bought a new SSD for my laptop.

If I boot Linux on it (it’s a dual boot system), the SSD works fine, but if I boot Windows the File Explorer says, that the drive is write-protected.

I already tried to do the following things:

- Using the Windows partiton manager to remove write protection (didn´t work)
- Using MiniTool to remove write protection (didn´t work)
- Using DISKPART to remove write protection (didn´t work)

  *Everywhere mentiond above the drive was not specified as write-protected. Only by the File Explorer.*
- Using CHKDSK /f to repair the SSD (didn’t work --> it told me, that it cannot repair because the drive has a readonly-filesystem. Without /f there where no problems recognized by the program)
- Adding a registry entry to not protect drives (didn’t work)

It’s really frustrating that a completely new and fine SSD (CrystalDisc score: 100%) is recognized wrongly by Windows.

Comment: I don't see that issue here.  Have you tried returning the SSD for a new one?

Comment: A few details need clarification: 1. What do you mean by "boot Linux on it"? Is "Linux" installed (and booting from) said SSD? Or is it booting from some other drive and while in Linux you can mount and read/write to the new SSD? If so, which file system is there, was it formatted in Linux? How exactly is it or isn't recognized in Windows Drive Manager?

Comment: By booting Linux I mean that I boot linux from another drive. Windows is also installed on that one.Linux can mount and read/write to the new SSD. I formatted it NTFS in Windows

Comment: So, at one time everything worked as it is supposed to... That being the case try disabling Windows' Fast Startup feature, something that is a must when dual-booting anyway. Then shutdown Windows to make it stick. The drive should be R/W as well but if not then boot Linux and try error correction tools there (Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives have the nice GUI tool Disks, select the drive, clcik the cogwheel button > repair filesystem). VERY important note: Linux does not and cannot fix NTFS errors, it merely runs `ntfsfix` under the hood with very limited capabilities BUT ... (...)

Comment: (...) It'll signal to Windows the drive needs fixing - `chkdsk` - and that should happen automatically at the next boot and before Windows boots to the desktop. Let it run and it should be fine afterwards. If after all this the problem persists, and irrespective of the drive being apparently fine in Linux, you should assume the drive is about to fail and replace it. Of course, have backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out just right now, that I only had to change some settings in gpedit.msc

These were under the system settings and drives. There I had to select, that new inbuilt drives shouldn´t be write-protected.

I´m really sorry that I wasted your time, but thanks for your help!

MatykoBr